# How to remove controller name and function name in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating a directory site in codeigniter. On landing page load it prompts to select state then city. Then it redirects from **www.example.com** to *www.example.com/location/city-name/*.

Here Site is the controller name and location is the function name within it.

I have already removed controller name from the url using route.php. Code is below:

```
$route['location/(:any)'] = 'site/location';
```

But I want to remove function name location too from the url and url should be **www.example.com/city-name/**.

Further when category is selected after selecting the city it should be redirected to **www.example.com/city-name/category-name/** but I am able to redirect to *www.example.com/location/city-name/category-name/* only using following lines in route.php:

```
$route['location/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'site/location';
```

I can capture city and category name using $this->uri->segment and use the same for filter process there is absolutely no issue with it.

But main issue remains to remove the function name **location**.

I have searched suggested questions before posting this question but could't find any suitable solution. Can anyone help me to achieve the goal?

My site controller is below:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Site extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->model('query_model'); 
    $this->load->library("pagination");
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));
    }
   public function index(){
    $this->load->view('website/index');
  }
  public function location(){
    $this->load->view('website/index');
  }
}
```

I think I am doing some mistake either in index or location function. Location Function is nothing just showing the view of index. Index view has the code to grab uri segment and filter the data accordingly.

My code which is passing state id to a jquery function:

```
<a onclick="get_cities(2)">Andaman &amp; Nicobar Islands</a>
```

My jquery code get_cities(id) is below:

```
        function get_cities(id){
        var aj_url="<?= base_url();?>ajax_post_controller/show_cities";
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: aj_url,
            data: {id: id,},
            success: function(res, status) {
                if (res)
                {
                    alert(res);
                    $("#loc-head").html("Select City");
                    $("#loc-data").html(res);
                    $(".modal-footer").css("display","block");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

After defining below code:
    $route['(:any)'] = 'site';
    $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'site';

Alert from get_cities function returning html code of index page and Index page is displayed in opened model too.

If I comment above two lines I get the list of cities it returns the url of city

```
<a href="http://example.com/visakhapatnam/">Visakhapatnam</a>
```

But due to above 2 route lines commented above city url give an error of 404.

Answer (score 1):

**hope this will help you :**

```
  $route['location'] = 'site/index'; /* redirect to index method */
  $route['location/(:any)'] = 'site/location'; /* redirect to location*/
  $route['location/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'site/location/$1';
```

Comment: I have changed editeted to "`$route['location/(:any)'] = 'site/$1'`". After selecting state and city from landing www.example.com it points to url  www.example.com/palasa-kasibugga/. It should display results filtered based on city selected. But it is displaying **404 Page Not Found**. Reason I couldn't understand.

Comment: it depends how your are redirecting the page and parameter passed

Comment: I am redirecting the page to *www.example.com/palasa-kasibugga/*. base_url().$city->slug;. If it is wrong can you give me an example for what my url should be?

Comment: where is location string u r redirecting all site url to go through with location , and also what is your default controller

Comment: Ok now I have added www.example.com/location/north-lakhimpur/. Still showing *404 Page Not Found*. I am editing the question to add my controller and location function.

Comment: if u set $route['location/(:any)'] = 'site/location'" will redirect to location method means  www.example.com/location/north-lakhimpur/ go to the location method of site controller

Comment: Hi Pradip I want to achieve *www.example.com/north-lakhimpur/* not _www.example.com/location/north-lakhimpur/_ kindly tell me the the route, url and method, if I have done totally wrong.

Comment: set ur route like this ; $route['default_controller'] = 'site';

$route['(:any)'] = 'site/location';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'site/location/$2';

Comment: http://localhost/testing/north-lakhimpur will go to the location method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168841/discussion-between-shubh-and-pradeep).

Comment: do some R&D ,unable to help you out ,sorry, office time is over i have to go

Answer (score 0):

add like this

**In routes.php**

```
$route['location/(.*)'] = 'site/index';
```

**In Controller**

```
public function index(){
    if($this->uri->segment(1) && $this->uri->segment(2)){
        $this->load->view('website/category');
    }elseif($this->uri->segment(1)){
        $this->load->view('website/city');
    }else{
        $this->load->view('website/index');
    }   
}
```